# Tomcat 6 and MySQL 5.x connection error on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

When attempting to connect to a MySQL 5.x database in a JSP webapplication running on Tomcat 6, I am getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:3307 connect,resolve)

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:3307 connect,resolve)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1699)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:405)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:268)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at org.apache.jsp.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:70)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

What could be the cause and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant bit of the trace:

> java.net.SocketException MESSAGE: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:3307 connect,resolve)

The webapp doesn't have the permission to connect/resolve the mentioned socket. You need to configure it at Tomcat level. Open `/conf/catalina.policy` and add the following block of code:

```
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:3307", "connect,resolve";
};
```

If you want to be a bit more restrictive, e.g. granting access to a specific JDBC driver only which is present in `/lib/filename.jar`, then add this instead:

```
grant codeBase "jar:file:${catalina.home}/lib/filename.jar!/-" {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:3307", "connect,resolve";
};
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the following lines

```
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
at org.apache.jsp.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:70)
```

indicate that you're connecting the DB inside a JSP file. Maybe you're just starting and learning, but I would only mention that this is not the best practice. DB connectivity should be done in its own classes which you in turn use in a servlet class which in turn forwards to the JSP which in turn displays the results. Calling the servlet by URL should then yield the same results, but you end up with better reuseable and maintainable code.

Comment: BalusC: Thank you so much for your reply.. it worked! and thanks for your suggestion about DB connectivity. Really appreciated.